Avoiding this escape in Swing component initialization
In more recent Java the linting error possible 'this' escape before subclass is fully initialized comes up a lot in Swing code. For example, calling AbstractAction.putValue() from the ctor.
    public class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
        private TrackModel model;

        public PauseAction(TrackModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            putValue(NAME, "Pause");
            // Bunch of other possible keys
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.pause();
        }
    }

Is it a fool's errand to try and avoid this warning?

I would use the factory pattern here
public class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
    private TrackModel model;

    private PauseAction(TrackModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.pause();
    }

    public static Action createPauseAction(TrackModel model) {
        PauseAction result = new PauseAction(model);
        result.putValue(NAME, "Pause");
        // Bunch of other possible keys
        return result;
    }
}

